# Why can't I access the facebook friends list after reopening a session in ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am upgrading to the facebook 3.0 sdk for ios. Things went well, until I tried to open an existing session after relaunching the application. I am trying to access the list of friends for the facebook user.

```
if ([[FBSession activeSession] isOpen]) {
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        //do something here
    }];
}else{
    [[self session] openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
        if ([self isValid]) {
            [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                //log this error we always get
                NSLog(@"%@",error);
                //do something else
            }];
        }
    }];
}
```

However I get this error:

```
Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0x1d92ff40 {com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={
  body =     {
    error =         {
        code = 2500;
        message = "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.";
        type = OAuthException;
    };
  };
  code = 400;
}, com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=400}
```

I've found that if I use the FBSession reauthorize method it allows me to complete the request without error, but it also means I must show UI or switch apps every time we relaunch the application which is unacceptable. Any suggestions on what I should be doing differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was not setting the session on the request after logging in. Simple mistake.

```
[[self session] openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
    if ([self isValid]) {
        //I should have been doing this
        request.session = [FBSession activeSession];
        [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
            //log this error we always get
            NSLog(@"%@",error);
            //do something else
        }];
    }
}];
```

Comment: Thanks, I never would've fixed this without your help! :)

Comment: what is  [self session] method?